# How to count number of open jobs and closed jobs of specific job card in sql?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, dsl

The requirement is to count the number of "open job" and the number of "closed jobs" of the "Technician" in the application.

if the field "status" is = "pending" or "work started" then the job is open, else the job status is closed

Im using a SQL script to count the number of open jobs and closed jobs, my problem is that I cant get it to count for a specific technician _id.

Here's my SQL script for counting open jobs:

```
select count(*)
from jobcard
  left join "user" on "user"."_id_" = jobcard.technicians_fk
where jobcard.status = "Pending"
```

but the problem comes in where i want to only count for a specific user id

Comment: Double quotes are for delimited identifiers, use single quotes for string literals. (Your `"Pending"` is a column name, the string should be `'Pending'`.)

Comment: You probably want to `GROUP BY "user"."_id_"`.

Comment: Is the jobcard column really called "technicians_fk"?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve]

Comment: Is the PK column of your user table really `_id_` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use conditional aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT
    u."_id_",
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE jc.status IN ('pending', 'word started')) AS open_cnt,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE jc.status NOT IN ('pending', 'word started')) AS closed_cnt
FROM "user" u
LEFT JOIN jobcard jc
    ON u."_id_" = jc.technicians_fk
GROUP BY
    u."_id_";
```

I don't know what Java has to do with this question, but you can't use the exact syntax above from something like JPA or Hibernate.  You might want to consider using a raw query for this particular problem.

Comment: Thank you, i'm still a beginner with less than 1 year experience.

Comment: In case where the table "User" has two columns, namely "amount of open jobs" and "amount of closed jobs", using the SQL script above, how would i populate the two columns with their result related to the query above? for example: if the result is "technician x has 20 open jobs and 30 closed jobs" how would i use that result to populate the two columns in the "user" table?

Comment: @GrantSolomons Sorry, I don't understand your follow up question, but in any case, you should probably open a new question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Good catch, which leads me to suspecr that maybe inner join might be acceptable to the OP, or perhaps the missing data were not noticed.